# Jetpack Compose "pops backstacks"/returns to home screen when updating literals with Live Edit

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, liveedit

Android Studio have a "Live Edit of literals" feature, but whenever I change a literal and I'm not on the homescreen, it pops back to the homescreen, resulting in I cannot see the updated view. Yesteday Android Studio Electric Eel was released with the Live Edit feature which should do the same, but for most components on the screen. But again same problem, the feature only works on my main page which renders it quite useless.

So, at the main page:
I add a button / rewrite some text -> it updates on my phone

If I navigate to another view and do the same, it updates, but pops me back to the main page, and I will have to open the view again to see the changes.

It says [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#live-edit) that *"Live Edit refreshes Compose Preview when changes are made to UI elements."*, so maybe it's not possible at all? Or is there someway to prevent this behaviour?

I can bypass this problem by changing my NavController startdestination, to the view I want to edit. But this seems inconvenient in many cases.

Also running Compose Previews works, but requires me defaulting all of my parameters.

Thank you!

Comment: Pretty irritating thing, I've disabled it - looks like it can only work reliably on small test projects so far. I suggest you [reporting](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) this problem.